# stuck with multi-level categories and sub-categories php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a little directory listing products. Currently I can list Categories (level1) and sub-categories (level2).
I want to add potentially a 3rd level which would be sub-subcategories (level3).
Adding is working but listing (looping) does not work as it limits me to 2 levels.

I need some help to figure it out.

Here is the code for adding and listing and th mysql structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `lcat_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lcat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lcat_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sub_cat` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

My code is:

```
<?php
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?action=newcat" method ="POST"> 
Category Name : <input type = "text" name = "cat_name" maxlength="250"><br><br>
Sub of category : <select name="lcat_id">
<option value=''>0</option>
<?php
$sql_cat = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * from ".TABLE_CATS." WHERE sub_cat='0' ORDER BY lcat_id") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
        while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cat)) {
        extract($row_cat);
        /*
        $id = $row_cat["lcat_id"];
        $name = $row_cat["lcat_name"];
        $sub_cat = $row_cat["sub_cat"];
        */
        echo "<option  value='".$row_cat["lcat_id"]."'>".$row_cat['lcat_name']."</option>";
            $sql_subcat = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * from ".TABLE_CATS." WHERE sub_cat='".$row_cat["lcat_id"]."' ") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
                while($row_subcat = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_subcat)) {
                extract($row_subcat);
                /*
                $id = $row_subcat["lcat_id"];
                $namea = $row_subcat["lcat_name"];
                $sub_cata = $row_subcat["sub_cat"];
                */
                echo "<option  value='".$row_subcat['lcat_id']."'>-> ".$row_subcat['lcat_name']."</option>";
                }
    }   
?>
</select>
<input type = "submit" value = "New Category"><br>
</form>
<?php
if ($_GET['action']=="newcat"){
        if ($_POST['cat_name']==""){
            print "You did not put anything.<br/><a href=".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].">Go back</a>";
            
        }

        $sql_cat = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT lcat_name from ".TABLE_CATS." WHERE lcat_name='".$_POST['cat_name']."' ") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
            while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cat)) {
            extract($row_cat);
            $name = $row_cat["lcat_name"];
            }
            if ($row_cat['cat_name']){
                print "Category <b>".$_POST['cat_name']."</b> already exists in <b>".$mysql_db."</b>.<br>Please chose new name.<br/><a href=".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].">Go back</a>";
                
            }

            $sql_subcat = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * from ".TABLE_CATS." WHERE sub_cat='".$row_cat['lcat_id']."' AND lcat_name='".$row_cat["lcat_name"]."'") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
                while($row_subcat = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_subcat)) {
                extract($row_subcat);
                $namea = $row_subcat["lcat_name"];
                $sub_cat = $row_subcat["sub_cat"];
        }

        if ($row_subcat['lcat_name']) {
            echo ("Sub-category <b>".$row_subcat['lcat_name']."</b> already exists in <b>$mysql_db</b>. Please chose new name.<br/><a href=".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].">Go back</a>");
            exit;
        } else {
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_CATS." (lcat_name, lcat_path, sub_cat) VALUES ('".$_POST['cat_name']."','".$_POST['cat_name']."','".$_POST['lcat_id']."')";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql_query);
            echo "You added category :<b> ".$_POST['cat_name']."</b> in <b>$mysql_db</b><br/><a href=".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].">Go back</a>.";
        }


}
?>
```

Comment: If you create a function which you pass in a start category and it returns all of the sub-categories, you can call it as needed.

Comment: any example please so I can start?

Comment: By `sub_cat` do you mean `parent_id`? What do you expect to have in `lcat_path`? You are missing a PK on this categories table.

Comment: lcat_path is basically the url slug , it's only there for seo. I do not have parent_ID, I'm using sub_cat info,

Comment: so `sub_cat` is a column to signify the parent of the current category? it doesn't have any foreign key reference to `lcat_id`? perhaps a (re)visit to [ask] would be best. this question definitely need a bit restructuring so its parts are clear in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by improving your categories table by -

- adding the primary key
- adding a foreign key constraint for parent_id
- removing redundant path column
- and removing the column name prefix (the table is already called categories)

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_category` FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Instead of having nested loops running queries to get child categories, or a recursive function, I would use a recursive [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to build and return the category hierarchy -

```
WITH RECURSIVE nested_cats AS (
    SELECT *, 0 `depth`, CAST(`name` AS CHAR(200)) AS `path`
    FROM `categories`
    WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `c`.*, `nc`.`depth` + 1, CONCAT(`nc`.`path`, ' > ', `c`.`name`)
    FROM `categories` `c`
    JOIN `nested_cats` `nc` ON `nc`.`id` = `c`.`parent_id`
)
SELECT * FROM `nested_cats` ORDER BY `path`;
```

In your current code you are building up your SQL by concatenating strings with user input without any validation. This makes your script rather vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). You should take some time to understand [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and how they help you to protect against SQLi. You are currently using MySQLi which provides support for prepared statements and parameterization but for my example I am using PDO, as I find it more intuitive.

```
<?php

// During development, report all PHP errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'db_user', 'db_pass');

$feedback = '';
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

/* IF IS POST DO ADD */
if ($action == 'New Category'){
    $cat_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cat_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    if (empty($cat_name)){
        $feedback = 'You did not put anything.';
    } else {

        $parent_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'parent_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => ['default' => null]]);

        // check to see if it already exists
        $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `name` FROM `categories` WHERE `name` = :name');

        // execute the prepared statement
        $statement->execute(['name' => $cat_name]);

        // retrieve result rows
        $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if ($rows) {
            $feedback = "Category {$rows[0]->name} already exists!";
        } else {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES (:name, :parent_id)');
            $stmt->execute([':name' => $cat_name, ':parent_id' => $parent_id]);
            $feedback =  "You added category: <b>{$cat_name}</b>.";
        }
    }
}

/* LOAD ALL CATEGORIES */
$sql = '
    WITH RECURSIVE `nested_cats` AS (
        SELECT *, 0 `depth`, CAST(`name` AS CHAR(200)) AS `path`
        FROM `categories`
        WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.*, `nc`.`depth` + 1, CONCAT(`nc`.`path`, " > ", `c`.`name`)
        FROM `categories` `c`
        JOIN `nested_cats` `nc` ON `nc`.`id` = `c`.`parent_id`
    )
    SELECT * FROM `nested_cats` ORDER BY `path`';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$categories = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<form action="" method ="POST">
Category Name : <input type="text" name="cat_name" maxlength="250"><br><br>
Sub of category : <select name="parent_id">
<option value=""> - </option>
<?php

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $indent = str_repeat('-> ', $category->depth);
    echo "<option  value='{$category->id}'>{$indent}{$category->name}</option>\r\n";
}

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="New Category"><br>
</form>

<div><?php echo $feedback; ?></div>
```

This is only a crude example and has no error checking/handling but it should get you moving in a better direction.

Comment: whaoou thansk a lot I will check this in the next coming days and let you know. I started rewriting my own code but definitely yours seems pretty good.

Comment: seems there is something wrong as I'm getting this: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool in /var/www/html/Admin/add_v3.php:53 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Admin/add_v3.php on line 53`

Comment: Assuming that your line 53 is `$categories = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` you could change line 52 to `$result = $pdo->query($sql) or die($pdo->errorInfo());` to see why the query is returning false. I just copied this code into a new file (and updated the PDO connection details) and it works fine.

Comment: changed line 52 and now getting this `Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/Admin/add_v3.php on line 52
Array`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that errorInfo returns an array. Try `or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));`. What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: I added the debug option and now getting this `Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'c.name' in 'field list' )` I'm using this version: 10.3.36-MariaDB-0+deb10u2 - Raspbian 10

Comment: That suggests that you have not changed the column names as suggested, in which case you need to amend them in either the table or the query.

Comment: I did create a brand new mysql table using your sql query so fields are correctly named

Comment: sorry forget it. I found the error. Bad naming of the mysql table as I renamed "categories" in "categories_v2" but not everywhere. So it's working I need to run more tests.